# filter multiple first objects in arr1 > obj1 > arr2 > obj2

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get just the first object who's 2nd arrays contain an object where the id is found. Example below ...

```
    const testProductId = 1;
    const tests = [
      {
        name: 'name1',
        subtotal: 2,
        products: [
          {
            productId: 1,
            subtotal: 123,
          },
          {
            productId: 2,
            subtotal: 123,
          },
          {
            productId: 1,
            subtotal: 100,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'name2',
        subtotal: 40,
        products: [
          {
            productId: 3,
            subtotal: 82671,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'name3',
        subtotal: 4,
        products: [
          {
            productId: 1,
            subtotal: 300,
          },
          {
            productId: 1,
            subtotal: 200,
          },
          {
            productId: 12,
            subtotal: 10,
          },
          {
            productId: 14,
            subtotal: 10,
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
```

given the following...
`tests.map((test) => test.products.filter((product) => product.productId === testProductId))`

will return...

```
[
  {
    name: "name1"
    subtotal: 2
    products: [
      {
        productId: 1
        subtotal: 123
      }, 
      {
        productId: 1
        subtotal: 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "name2"
    subtotal: 40
    products: []
  },
  {
    name: "name3"
    subtotal: 4
    products: [
      {
        productId: 1
        subtotal: 300
      }, 
      {
        productId: 1
        subtotal: 200
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This works, but how would I get a result without the 2nd object if the array is empty?

Comment: just add more filtering conditions

Comment: @DanielA.White see my answer below. If i combine that filter with the end condition and don't re-instantiation products, then it would include the unwanted 2nd object of the first object.

Answer (score 0):

This currently works, but I would like to see if there is another answer without having to instantiate the sub array in every object...

```
tests.filter((test) => {
  test.products = test.products.filter((product) => product.productId === testProductId);
  return test.products.length > 0;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have chosen the `forEach` with an `if` condition.

```js
const testProductId = 1;
const tests = [
      {
        name: 'name1',
        subtotal: 2,
        products: [
          {
            productId: 1,
            subtotal: 123,
          },
          {
            productId: 2,
            subtotal: 123,
          },
          {
            productId: 1,
            subtotal: 100,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'name2',
        subtotal: 40,
        products: [
          {
            productId: 3,
            subtotal: 82671,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'name3',
        subtotal: 4,
        products: [
          {
            productId: 1,
            subtotal: 300,
          },
          {
            productId: 1,
            subtotal: 200,
          },
          {
            productId: 12,
            subtotal: 10,
          },
          {
            productId: 14,
            subtotal: 10,
          },
        ],
      },
    ];

r = [];
tests.forEach((test) => { 
  let res = test.products.filter((product) => product.productId === testProductId)
  if (res.length > 0) {    
    r.push(res);
  };
})

console.log(r)
```

Comment: I think this is more expensive than the answer I gave. Not only are you instantiating based on the filter, but you are calling push which an additional instantiation per iteration.

Comment: @FiddleFreak It may be that you are right and it is "more expensive". I haven't done any tests on this. But of course I would be interested. It's a solution that could fix the problem you described. As so often: It depends ;-) Cheers